# database implementation in window based application

Tags: iphone

I am new in iPhone programming. I am making an application in which there is need of database implementation to store the data. But I dont know how should I start for it. Application is window based. Please give me some hint so that I would be able to implement database concept.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say:
 **Try to learn core data**

It might take some time to learn but

1. It will save you so much time that will return all the time you spent learning.
2. It will open possibilities in your app you might avoid using sqlite.
3. When you get it it the easiest thing you tried

I started here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

And used that:

[http://www.amazon.com/Core-Data-Apples-API-Persisting/dp/1934356328/ref=pd_sim_b_3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356328)

And it is time to know Ray

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone (more correctly, iOS) [includes SQLite](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html) for database storage. You may want to avoid the low-level stuff and use the Apple-blessed approach [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) framework.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to use Coredata. I'll say the best starting point will be to read some apple docs on the subject. Have a read [Coredata guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

I can't see the point rewriting the guide here as it already exist.

Good luck!